# The opposite of assert_select?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, functional-testing

I am writing an app where it is desirable to check if a view does *not* have some functionality - in particular because that functionality must be presented only to users in certain security group. I am looking for the opposite of assert_selects in order to see that a menu is *not* rendered.

Answer (score 70, accepted):

Take a look at the docs here:

http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/Assertions/SelectorAssertions/assert_select

From the docs:

assert_select is an `assertion that selects elements and makes one or more equality tests.`

and from the equality tests sections:

> The equality test may be one of the following:
>
> true - Assertion is true if at least one element selected.
>
> false - Assertion is true if no element selected.
>
> String/Regexp - Assertion is true if the text value of at least one
>   element matches the string or regular expression.
>
> Integer - Assertion is true if exactly that number of elements are
>   selected.
>
> Range - Assertion is true if the number of selected elements fit the
>   range.
>
> If no equality test specified, the assertion is true if at least one
>   element selected.

And a simple example:

```
   # Page contains no forms
   assert_select "form", false, "This page must contain no forms"
```

Comment: The solution from @Gant Laborde worked for me where I had to select the inner text to differentiated between two otherwise identical elements. Otherwise, I would recommend this solution.

Comment: The dom testing methods were extracted to the new repository `rails-dom-testing`. Here's [the latest `assert_select` documentation](https://github.com/rails/rails-dom-testing/blob/master/lib/rails/dom/testing/assertions/selector_assertions.rb#L163).

Answer (score 51):

Don't forget you can always pass in the count, and set that to zero.

```
assert_select "a", {count: 0, text: "New"}, "This page must contain no anchors that say New"
```

Comment: This does not work for me: No exception is raised even when the element is found.

Comment: Update: It is working fine for any element other than 'body'.

Comment: Good to know!   Thanks @MatijsvanZuijlen

Answer (score 2):

You can easily define your own:

```
module ActionDispatch::Assertions::SelectorAssertions
  def refute_select(*a,&b)
    begin
      assert_select(*a,&b)
    rescue AssertionFailedError
      return
    end
    raise "fail" # there should be a better built-in alternative
  end
end
```

Comment: This is not going to work as `AssertionFailedError` is raised before negation is evaluated.

Comment: You could name it `refute_select`? `refute` seems to be a commonly-used antonym for `assert` in Rails, e.g. https://apidock.com/ruby/v1_9_3_125/MiniTest/Assertions/refute

Comment: @JonSchneider, I like it. Please edit this answer if you want.

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem to ensure there WASN'T a 'Delete' button, out of many buttons. The accepted answer would not work in this situation because there are already several buttons.

```
assert_select '.button' do |btn|
  btn.each do |b|
    assert_no_match 'Delete', b.to_s
  end
end
```

However, I really like GantMan's answer better!