# How to assert that a link does not exist rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

To test that a link exists in my view I do the following:

```
assert_select 'a[href=?]', '/post/new', :text => 'New post'
```

Now I'm searching for a way to test where a link not exists in the view,
how can I do that?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Check this [doc](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Assertions/SelectorAssertions.html#method-i-assert_select).

Taken from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9025717/the-opposite-of-assert-select). Hope it help.